On submit delete data is also showing
I'm building a simple to-do app in React where I can add and delete items. However, after I delete an item, the deleted item reappears when I submit a new one. I've checked the state in the console, and it shows the correct data, but the UI still displays the deleted item.Thanks for the help in advance
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/w9lvkr
App.js
import { useState } from "react";
import Input from "./Inputs/Input";
import Items from "./Items/Items";

import "./styles/App.scss";

export default function App() {
  const [formData, setInitFormData] = useState([]);
  const inputHandler = (data) => {
    setInitFormData(data);
  };
  const dataAftrDelInPar = (delData) => {
    const updatedFormData = formData.filter((item) => item.id !== delData.id);
    console.log("update form data:", updatedFormData);
    setInitFormData(updatedFormData);
    console.log("After Deleted:", delData);
  };
  return (
    <div className="container w-[70%] mt-5">
      <h1>To Do App</h1>
      <Input FrmData={inputHandler} />
      <Items listData={formData} deletedDataToPr={dataAftrDelInPar} />
    </div>
  );
}

Item.js
import { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import { CheckIcon, PencilIcon } from "@heroicons/react/24/solid";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import { faTrashAlt } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";

export default function Items({ listData, deletedDataToPr }) {
  const [frmValue, setFrmVal] = useState(listData);
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState(null);
  const [updateInp, setUpdateInp] = useState(null);
  const [editVal, setEditVal] = useState(null);
  const updatedFrmRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    setFrmVal(listData);
  }, [listData]);

  const deleteHandler = (val) => {
    const BefrdeleteData = [...frmValue];
    const AftrdeleteData = BefrdeleteData.filter((currFl, ind) => ind !== val);
    setFrmVal(AftrdeleteData);
    deletedDataToPr(AftrdeleteData);
    setSelected(null);
  };

  const doneHandler = (doneVal) => {
    setSelected(doneVal);
  };

  const updateHandler = (updateVal) => {
    console.log(`currently clicked is ${updateVal}`);
    setUpdateInp(updateVal);
    setEditVal(frmValue[updateVal]);
  };

  const editFrmSave = (saveFrmVal) => {
    const updatedData = [...frmValue];
    updatedData[saveFrmVal] = updatedFrmRef.current.value;
    setFrmVal(updatedData);
    setUpdateInp(null);
  };

  return (
    <>
      {frmValue.map((currEl, index) => (
        <div
          className="justify-between flex items-center rounded-md bg-blue-50 my-3 px-2 py-2 ring-1 ring-inset ring-blue-700/10"
          key={index}
        >
          {updateInp === index ? (
            <div className="grid grid-cols-12 gap-4 items-center">
              <div className="col-span-9">
                <input
                  type="text"
                  className="border border-gray-300 p-1"
                  defaultValue={editVal}
                  ref={updatedFrmRef}
                />
              </div>
              <div className="col-span-3 px-2">
                <button
                  type="submit"
                  className="w-full px-4 py-2 bg-blue-500 text-white rounded hover:bg-blue-600"
                  onClick={() => {
                    editFrmSave(index);
                  }}
                >
                  Submit
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          ) : (
            <>
              <h2
                className={`text-lg font-medium text-blue-700 ${
                  selected === index ? "line-through text-red-500" : ""
                }`}
              >
                {currEl}
              </h2>
              <div className="justify-between flex items-center">
                <button
                  className="p-1.5 flex items-center space-x-2 text-red-500 rounded"
                  onClick={() => {
                    deleteHandler(index);
                  }}
                >
                  <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faTrashAlt} />
                </button>
                <button
                  onClick={() => {
                    doneHandler(index);
                  }}
                  className="p-1.5"
                >
                  <CheckIcon className="w-6 h-6 text-green-500" />
                </button>
                <button
                  onClick={() => {
                    updateHandler(index);
                  }}
                  className="p-1.5"
                >
                  <PencilIcon className="h-4 w-4 text-blue-500" />
                </button>
              </div>
            </>
          )}
        </div>
      ))}
    </>
  );
}


State management is done at different levels of components in the given code, leading to such errors. To avoid such logical errors, try to keep state and state mutation functions at the same level and drill those down together, or use global state management with a context provider.

Duplicated states go out of synch. This is the issue with the present code.
The state formData is a state maintained in the root component. The state initVal in Input component and the state frmValue in Items components are basically duplicated with respect to formData.  And the code fails in some areas to get these two duplicated states in synch with the state in the root component.
A refactored code has given below. Please see the Test run results given below prior to proceeding to the refactored code.
The refactored code given below removes the duplication, and uses only the state formData in the root component. This state will get updated in add, edit and delete events. The duplicated states and the related codes are removed just for brevity. Please do take advantage of the comments given in the handlers wherein the codes have been changed.
App.js
import { useState } from 'react';

import Input from './Inputs/Input';
import Items from './Items/Items';

export default function App() {
  const [formData, setInitFormData] = useState([]);

  const inputHandler = (data) => {

    // upon adding a new item, the data received
    // over will be the newly added data.
    // It will be appended to the list as below.

    setInitFormData([...formData, data]);
  };

  const dataAftrDelInPar = (delData) => {
   
    // Upon deleting or modifying an item, the new list
    // will receive over, the same list is just updated to the 
    // state.

    setInitFormData(delData);
  };

  return (
    <div className="container w-[70%] mt-5">
      <h1>To Do App</h1>
      <Input FrmData={inputHandler} />
      <Items listData={formData} deletedDataToPr={dataAftrDelInPar} />
    </div>
  );
}

Input.js
import { useState, useRef } from 'react';
export default function Input({ FrmData }) {
  const formRef = useRef(null);

  const submitHandler = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const inpVal = formRef.current.value;

    // The prop FrmData is the handler to inputHandler,
    // therefore it is invoked here with the new data.

    FrmData(inpVal);
    formRef.current.value = '';
  };
  return (
    <form
      action="/submit"
      method="POST"
      className="grid grid-cols-12 gap-4 items-center"
      onSubmit={submitHandler}
    >
      <div className="col-span-9">
        <input
          id="first-name"
          name="first-name"
          type="text"
          autoComplete="given-name"
          className="w-full rounded-md border-0 py-2 text-gray-900 shadow-sm ring-1 ring-inset ring-gray-300"
          required
          ref={formRef}
        />
      </div>
      <div className="col-span-3 px-2">
        <button
          type="submit"
          className="w-full px-4 py-2 bg-blue-500 text-white rounded hover:bg-blue-600"
        >
          Submit
        </button>
      </div>
    </form>
  );
}

Items.js
import { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import { CheckIcon, PencilIcon } from '@heroicons/react/24/solid';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import { faTrashAlt } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';

export default function Items({ listData, deletedDataToPr }) {
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState(null);
  const [updateInp, setUpdateInp] = useState(null);
  const [editVal, setEditVal] = useState(null);
  const updatedFrmRef = useRef(null);

  const deleteHandler = (val) => {
    const BefrdeleteData = [...listData];
    const AftrdeleteData = BefrdeleteData.filter((currFl, ind) => ind !== val);

    // The latest list excluding the deleted one is
    // updated here to the state in root component

    deletedDataToPr(AftrdeleteData);
    setSelected(null);
  };

  const doneHandler = (doneVal) => {
    setSelected(doneVal);
  };

  const updateHandler = (updateVal) => {
    console.log(`currently clicked is ${updateVal}`);
    setUpdateInp(updateVal);
    //    setEditVal(frmValue[updateVal]);
    setEditVal(listData[updateVal]);
  };

  const editFrmSave = (saveFrmVal) => {
    const updatedData = [...listData];
    updatedData[saveFrmVal] = updatedFrmRef.current.value;

    // Here also, the modified list including the changes
    // will be updated to the state in the root component.
    // Note : Since the same handler has been used for both
    // deleting and modification, please change the name of this
    // prop into a more meaningful one.

    deletedDataToPr(updatedData);
    setUpdateInp(null);
  };

  // Please note the map function has invoked on the prop directly.
  return (
    <>
      {listData.map((currEl, index) => (
        <div
          className="justify-between flex items-center rounded-md bg-blue-50 my-3 px-2 py-2 ring-1 ring-inset ring-blue-700/10"
          key={index}
        >
          {updateInp === index ? (
            <div className="grid grid-cols-12 gap-4 items-center">
              <div className="col-span-9">
                <input
                  type="text"
                  className="border border-gray-300 p-1"
                  defaultValue={editVal}
                  ref={updatedFrmRef}
                />
              </div>
              <div className="col-span-3 px-2">
                <button
                  type="submit"
                  className="w-full px-4 py-2 bg-blue-500 text-white rounded hover:bg-blue-600"
                  onClick={() => {
                    editFrmSave(index);
                  }}
                >
                  Submit
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          ) : (
            <>
              <h2
                className={`text-lg font-medium text-blue-700 ${
                  selected === index ? 'line-through text-red-500' : ''
                }`}
              >
                {currEl}
              </h2>
              <div className="justify-between flex items-center">
                <button
                  className="p-1.5 flex items-center space-x-2 text-red-500 rounded"
                  onClick={() => {
                    deleteHandler(index);
                  }}
                >
                  <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faTrashAlt} />
                </button>
                <button
                  onClick={() => {
                    doneHandler(index);
                  }}
                  className="p-1.5"
                >
                  <CheckIcon className="w-6 h-6 text-green-500" />
                </button>
                <button
                  onClick={() => {
                    updateHandler(index);
                  }}
                  className="p-1.5"
                >
                  <PencilIcon className="h-4 w-4 text-blue-500" />
                </button>
              </div>
            </>
          )}
        </div>
      ))}
    </>
  );
}

Test run
Two items have been added.

Changing the item B to C


Deleting the item C, the below list is after the deletion.

Adding another item D to the list, this is after the above deletion.


Thanks for the help @WeDoTheBest4You. The issue is solved and working fine

Thanks to you too, for your confirmation and the vote.
